# Out of bounds error with an identical code

Tags: java, android

I have 2 buttons. When you press the button and if you answer correctly a new question appears. When you answer the last question an alert dialog pops out and you can choose to end the game or restart. Now the problem is is that if on the last question I press true, everything works and I get the alert. if I press false I get: Index out of bounds error. The codes are identical(except for the part where I define witch button is true witch false). For example:

I have 3 questions. If I choose:

```
True, true, true = no errors. Correct.
True, false, true = no errors. Correct.
false, true, true = no errors. Correct.
```

But:

```
True, true, false = Invalid index 3, size is 3.
True, false, false = Invalid index 3, size is 3.
False, false, false = Invalid index 3, size is 3.
```

This is my True button code:

```
mTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();

                btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //if the question is true show next question/else close app
                        if (type.get(count[0])) {

                            scores++; // Add +1 to the score;
                            if (questions.size() - 1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                            {
                                // if its the last question open dialog to choose end game or restart;
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("WInner");
                                builder.setMessage("The score is " + scores);
                                builder.setCancelable(false);
                                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                // just close dialog
                                                dialog.cancel();


                                            }
                                        });
                                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                                score();

                                                Intent gryzti = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LevelSelectActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(gryzti);

                                            }
                                        });

                                // Create dialog from builder
                                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                                // Show dialog
                                alert.show();
                                count[0] = 0;

                            } else if (questions.size() - 1 < count[0])
                                try {
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid ");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            else  // if the question is not the last show the next question.
                                count[0]++;

                            mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                            pwindo.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            count[0]++;
                            pwindo.dismiss();
                            mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

This is my False button:

```
mFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();

                btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (!type.get(count[0])) {

                            scores++;
                            if (questions.size() - 1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                            {
                                // if its the last question open dialog to choose end game or restart;
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("WInner");
                                builder.setMessage("The score is " + scores);
                                builder.setCancelable(false);
                                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                // just close dialog
                                                dialog.cancel();

                                            }
                                        });
                                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                                                score();

                                                Intent gryzti = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LevelSelectActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(gryzti);

                                            }
                                        });

                                // Create dialog from builder
                                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                                // Show dialog
                                alert.show();
                                count[0] = 0;

                            } else if (questions.size() - 1 < count[0])
                                try {
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid ");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            else
                                count[0]++;

                            mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                            pwindo.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            count[0]++;
                            mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                            pwindo.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

Logcat:

```
02-09 14:57:37.970  21937-21937/com.mycompany.tiesaarmelas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.tiesaarmelas, PID: 21937
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            **at com.mycompany.tiesaarmelas.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:216)**
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Please include logcat output, and highlight lines mentioned in it.

Comment: Posted the logcat. It mentions a line 216. The code there is: mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem. In dont know if it's that but It will give  you problems when you fail an answer. WHat will happen if you fail the last question? YOu go for the else statment and count will increase, and after that you set the text. If You are in the last question (2) and then fail count will increase to 3 and set the text to this question that is out if index.

```
   .....
} else {
   count[0]++;
   mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); 
   pwindo.dismiss();
}
```

Solution:

```
  else if(questions.size()-1 > count[0])
 {
        count[0]++;
                 mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
 }else
      // you can restart again or finish
```

Also you should change that in the true button

Comment: With your code at the first question I cant close the popupwindow. I press the close btn and nothing happens. But I think you have the right answer. If I change my last question Boolean to false. Then the false button works, but not the true.. Hovewer like I said, your code hassome issues and I don't know what are they..

Comment: Which close btn? Could u tell me what are u answering and if it is the correct answer or not?

Answer (score 0):

You increment `count[0]` after you check to make sure it's in bounds.

```
else if (questions.size() - 1 < count[0])
    try {
       ...
    }
else
    count[0]++; //here
```

Aside from this, If you are ever duplicating code, it's a tip off that you're probably no doing it right.

Comment: Without this increment my questions aren't changing.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!type.get(count[0]))` in the false button, `if(type.get(count[0]))` in the true button. Could be to do with this method call, but becasue we don't know what `type.get(count[0]))` should do it is impossible to tell.

Comment: My questions are assigned to Booleans. When I press true button it checks is my question true or not. If its true then I add +1 to my score and show next question. If I presses true but the question is false I don't add +1 too my score but still show the next question. And vice versa with the false button.